# Collect elements into memory from source xml to be outputted once all have been found

Tags: xslt

I have a source xml that looks something like this:

```
<item>
    <id>1</id>
    <property name="representative_email"><value>Jallu.Kola@foo.bar.com</value></property>
    <property name="representative_name"><value>Jallu Kola</value></property>
    <property name="representative_phone"><value>555 123 456</value></property>
    <property name="representative_email"><value>Sala.Rakas@foo.bar.com</value></property>
    <property name="representative_name"><value>Sala Rakas</value></property>
    <property name="representative_phone"><value>555 2314 124</value></property>
</item>
<item>
    <id>2</id>
    <property name="representative_email"><value>Sala.Rakas@foo.bar.com</value></property>
    <property name="representative_name"><value>Sala Rakas</value></property>
    <property name="representative_phone"><value>555 2314 124</value></property>
</item>
<item>
    <id>3</id>
    <property name="representative_email"><value>Jallu.Kola@foo.bar.com</value></property>
    <property name="representative_name"><value>Jallu Kola</value></property>
    <property name="representative_phone"><value>555 123 456</value></property>
    <property name="representative_email"><value>Sala.Rakas@foo.bar.com</value></property>
    <property name="representative_name"><value>Sala Rakas</value></property>
    <property name="representative_phone"><value>555 2314 124</value></property>
    <property name="representative_email"><value>ville.kalle@foo.bar.com</value></property>
    <property name="representative_name"><value>Ville Kalle</value></property>
    <property name="representative_phone"><value>555 124 124124</value></property>
</item>
```

Unfortunately there's not much I can do about this other than use xslt to convert it to something more sensible.
I would like to convert it to look like this:

```
<item>
    <id>
    <representatives>
        <representative>
            <email></email>
            <name></name>
            </phone></phone>
        </representative
    </representatives
</item>
```

Any ideas how this can be achieved with xslt?I'm thinking that I need to collect the representative_* elements into memory while procedding an  element. Once the end of that item element is reached, I should output the new  element. Under that I would need to create a  element for each group of the email+name+phone elements that appear in sequence.

Comment: Are representative_* props appear in groups by 3 always? Or it's possible some of them could be missing?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no quarantee that they appear in groups of 3. So it's possible that some of them could be missing.

Comment: Some of them or any of them? Is there one which appears always?

Comment: If you have "email" then "name". How do you know if it's one representative with both email and name or two of them when first has only email, the second has only name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if each group always contain all 3 elements, you could iterate over one of them then select others by the same position:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
  <item>
    <xsl:copy-of select="id"/>
    <representatives>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="property[@name='representative_email']"/>
    </representatives>
  </item>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="property">
  <representative>
    <email>
      <xsl:value-of select="../property[@name='representative_email'][position()]"/>
    </email>
    <name>
      <xsl:value-of select="../property[@name='representative_name'][position()]"/>
    </name>
    <phone>
      <xsl:value-of select="../property[@name='representative_phone'][position()]"/>
    </phone>
  </representative>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I'm going with this solution and requiring that a "representative_name" is found in the original xml. Thanks.

Comment: @kosoant: +1 for your question. You may be interested to see a more generic solution in which the element names and properties per "representative" aren't hardcoded as in this solution, but can be externally-provided/dynamically-calculated. :)

Answer (score 1):

An XSLT 2.0 solution :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"></xsl:output>
    <xsl:template match="*|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*"/>            
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="id"/>
            <representatives>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="property" group-adjacent="count(preceding::*[@name=current()/@name])">
                    <representative>
                        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                            <xsl:element name="{substring-after(@name,'_')}">
                                <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </representative>
                </xsl:for-each-group>                
            </representatives>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You must have property name with a '_' in it. It works by taking for the first representative the first group of properties that have a different name in document order and goes on like that for the rest of the document.

I assume a root for your document (named `items`). The result of the XSLT is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
   <item>
      <id>1</id>
      <representatives>
         <representative>
            <email>Jallu.Kola@foo.bar.com</email>
            <name>Jallu Kola</name>
            <phone>555 123 456</phone>
         </representative>
         <representative>
            <email>Sala.Rakas@foo.bar.com</email>
            <name>Sala Rakas</name>
            <phone>555 2314 124</phone>
         </representative>
      </representatives>
   </item>
   <item>
      <id>2</id>
      <representatives>
         <representative>
            <email>Sala.Rakas@foo.bar.com</email>
            <name>Sala Rakas</name>
            <phone>555 2314 124</phone>
         </representative>
      </representatives>
   </item>
   <item>
          <id>3</id>
      <representatives>
         <representative>
            <email>Jallu.Kola@foo.bar.com</email>
            <name>Jallu Kola</name>
            <phone>555 123 456</phone>
         </representative>
         <representative>
            <email>Sala.Rakas@foo.bar.com</email>
            <name>Sala Rakas</name>
            <phone>555 2314 124</phone>
         </representative>
         <representative>
            <email>ville.kalle@foo.bar.com</email>
            <name>Ville Kalle</name>
                <phone>555 124 124124</phone>
         </representative>
      </representatives>
   </item>
</items>
```

Comment: This looks really nice, but unfortunately I'm using Xalan to process the xml and it does not support this.

Comment: May be you can change to saxon (see https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/9.3/saxonhe9-3-0-5j.zip/download), the cost of changing Xalan isn't that high and XSLT 2.0 is a far more powerfull langage than XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a more generic solution, that is also short (37 well-formatted lines) and simple**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pNumProps" select="3"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
         </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item">
  <item>
   <id><xsl:value-of select="id"/></id>
   <representatives>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=
     "property[position() mod $pNumProps = 1]"/>
   </representatives>
  </item>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="property">
  <representative>
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="gen" select=
   ".|following-sibling::property
             [not(position() >= $pNumProps)]"/>
  </representative>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="property" mode="gen">
  <xsl:element name="{substring-after(@name,'_')}">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML fragment** (wrapped into a single top element to make it a well-formed XML document):

```
<items>
 <item>
    <id>1</id>
    <property name="representative_email"><value>Jallu.Kola@foo.bar.com</value></property>
    <property name="representative_name"><value>Jallu Kola</value></property>
    <property name="representative_phone"><value>555 123 456</value></property>
    <property name="representative_email"><value>Sala.Rakas@foo.bar.com</value></property>
    <property name="representative_name"><value>Sala Rakas</value></property>
    <property name="representative_phone"><value>555 2314 124</value></property>
 </item>
 <item>
    <id>2</id>
    <property name="representative_email"><value>Sala.Rakas@foo.bar.com</value></property>
    <property name="representative_name"><value>Sala Rakas</value></property>
    <property name="representative_phone"><value>555 2314 124</value></property>
 </item>
 <item>
    <id>3</id>
    <property name="representative_email"><value>Jallu.Kola@foo.bar.com</value></property>
    <property name="representative_name"><value>Jallu Kola</value></property>
    <property name="representative_phone"><value>555 123 456</value></property>
    <property name="representative_email"><value>Sala.Rakas@foo.bar.com</value></property>
    <property name="representative_name"><value>Sala Rakas</value></property>
    <property name="representative_phone"><value>555 2314 124</value></property>
    <property name="representative_email"><value>ville.kalle@foo.bar.com</value></property>
    <property name="representative_name"><value>Ville Kalle</value></property>
    <property name="representative_phone"><value>555 124 124124</value></property>
 </item>
</items>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<items>
   <item>
      <id>1</id>
      <representatives>
         <representative>
            <email>Jallu.Kola@foo.bar.com</email>
            <name>Jallu Kola</name>
            <phone>555 123 456</phone>
         </representative>
         <representative>
            <email>Sala.Rakas@foo.bar.com</email>
            <name>Sala Rakas</name>
            <phone>555 2314 124</phone>
         </representative>
      </representatives>
   </item>
   <item>
      <id>2</id>
      <representatives>
         <representative>
            <email>Sala.Rakas@foo.bar.com</email>
            <name>Sala Rakas</name>
            <phone>555 2314 124</phone>
         </representative>
      </representatives>
   </item>
   <item>
      <id>3</id>
      <representatives>
         <representative>
            <email>Jallu.Kola@foo.bar.com</email>
            <name>Jallu Kola</name>
            <phone>555 123 456</phone>
         </representative>
         <representative>
            <email>Sala.Rakas@foo.bar.com</email>
            <name>Sala Rakas</name>
            <phone>555 2314 124</phone>
         </representative>
         <representative>
            <email>ville.kalle@foo.bar.com</email>
            <name>Ville Kalle</name>
            <phone>555 124 124124</phone>
         </representative>
      </representatives>
   </item>
</items>
```

**Do note**:

1. The number of properties per "representative" is specified in the externally provided global parameter `$pNumProps`.
2. The name of the element to generate is automatically produced (not hardcoded as in the accepted answer) as the string following '_' in the `name` attribute of a `property`.